# Add default values while merging tables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading two csv files with pandas.

```
df1= pd.read_csv('file_1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv')
data =  pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id')
```

The problem I'm facing is that the final data frame, data, has fewer rows since some id values are missing from both input files.What I'll like to do is to have a default value for all the cells in both cases, like:

```
data =  pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id',default_vaue=0)
```

Comment: What about `data =  pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id',how='outer').fillna(0)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outer join` and replace `NaN`s by `0`:

Notice: All N`aN`s are replaced by `0`, so `NaN`s in `df1` or `df2` are replaced too.

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id',how='outer').fillna(0)
```