# Add default value to merge in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Similar to this topic : [Add default values while merging tables in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696262/add-default-values-while-merging-tables-in-pandas)

The answer to this topic fills all `NaN` in the resulting DataFrame and that's not what I want to do.

Let's imagine the following situation : I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. Each of this DataFrame might contains some `Nan`, the columns of `df1` are `'a'` and `col1`, the columns of `df2` are `'a'` and `col2` where col1 and col2 are disjoints list of columns name (For example df1 and df2 could have respectively `'a', 'b', 'c'` and `'a', 'd', 'e'` as columns names). I want to perform a left merge on `df1` and `df2` and fill all the missing values of that merge(any row of `df1` with a value of the column `'a'` that is not a value of column `'a'` in df2) with a default value. We can imagine that I have a dict `default_values` that match any element of `col2` to a default values.

To give you a concrete example :

```
df1
   a         b         c
0  0  0.038108  0.961687
1  1  0.107457  0.616689
2  2  0.661485  0.240353
3  3  0.457169  0.560912
4  5  5.000000  5.000000

df2
   a         d         e
0  0  0.405170  0.934776
1  1  0.684532  0.168738
2  2  0.729693  0.967310
3  3  0.844770       NaN
4  4  0.842673  0.941324

default_values = {'d':42, 'e':43}
```

Expected Output :

```
   a         b         c         d         e
0  0  0.038108  0.961687  0.405170  0.934776
1  1  0.107457  0.616689  0.684532  0.168738
2  2  0.661485  0.240353  0.729693  0.967310
3  3  0.457169  0.560912  0.844770       NaN
4  5  5.000000  5.000000        42        43
```

Answer (score 2):

While writing this question, I found a working solution. I still think it's an interesting question. Here's a solution to get the expected output :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(default_values,
                   index = df1.set_index('a').index.difference(df2.a))
df3['a'] = df3.index
df1.merge(pd.concat((df2, df3), sort=False))
```

This solution works for a left/right merge, and it can be extended to work for an outer merge (by completing the first dataframe as well).

Edit : The `how='left'` argument is not specified in my merge because the DataFrame I'm merging with is constructed to have all the value of the column 'a' in df1 in its own column 'a'. We could add an `how='left'` to this call of merge, and it would give the same output.